# How do I reach the Arch-Mage?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I started the "Under Saarthal" quest a while ago but stopped because I couldn't find the Arch-Mage as the final part of that quest.

Now I'm working on it again but no matter how many times I leave and come back, wait, load previous save files, or wonder aimlessly around the college, the Arch-Mage will not come down from the upstairs door in his quarters. And a key is required to open that door but for me to obtain it, I will receive it after he dies.

I've looked at so many others' similar questions but am not finding an answer. 
I've gone back to Saarthal and spoke with Tolfdir. A lot of people were saying that he's either in the courtyard or sitting in a chair in his room, which he isn't. At first I didn't realize it was to that top door because when I have the quest selected, it sends me out of the college and behind it between the college and sky temple ruins. I can't access the area where he is by going through the hall of attainment. I've tried going elsewhere and waiting and sleeping and returning but nothing changes. He doesn't go to bed, he doesn't come out at all. I'm thinking I must have missed something. Someone else wrote that I had to get the scroll first from alftand, I've had that before I reached this problem.

Comment: Have you tried opening the door? A key is required to unlock it, but it isn't always locked. If you have, try going somewhere else, like White run sleep 48 hours, then go back to the college. Try the door during the day.

Comment: I've done that. I've done every obvious thing.

Comment: Can you edit in what other questions you've looked at and which solutions you've tried?

Comment: The UESP wiki says that after Tolfdir asks you to report to the archmage, "Savos will skip his entire schedule and will sit in his quarters, reading a book all day long and only takes a break to wander around between 2am and 7am." Have you wandered the college during those hours? And where does the quest marker point then? Are you on a PC? If so, have you tried console commands?

Comment: Also, to clarify: when you try to access the area the quest marker points to, do you only try the Hall of Attainment, or do you try the Hall of Elements as well? The door opposite the Arcanaeum is the Archmage's quarters.

Comment: I've read about console commands but I'm on PS3. I don't remember the hours in which I've wandered the college but he is never in is room. I've come back and left countless times. Every time the quest marker wants be to exit the college or go through the locked door in the Arch Mage's quarters.

Comment: I've gone through every door except the locked one.

Comment: Including the Middens? If the quest marker is pointing behind the college, maybe he's in the outdoor area you reach through the Middens. If not, sounds like you will have to go back to a really old save, or just drop it.

Comment: I've never heard of the Middens so I'm going to try that now. Thanks.

Comment: Are you on PC? Console commands might help.

Answer (score 2):

Appearently, this is a glitch. The only solutions are:

1. Using cheats. Type `prid 0001C1B8` and then type `moveto player`. You can also use cheats on the locked Arch Mage quarters door and type     unlock.
2. Wait until the Arch-Mage is back downstairs.
3. Look in the Middens, the arrow might be pointing behind the College where the exit is.

If you still can't solve the problem, try fast traveling somewhere else and then go back otherwise, reload an old save.